# Where does this answer come from? $2x^2+4x+c-1=0$

Tags: quadratics, conic-sections, discriminant

Note: I could do a simple algebra solution but the question wants me to answer this question using something that relates to parabola function.

That question is "if $2x^2+4x+c-1=0$ what is c?"
the solution in the answer sheet is about you somehow turn that equation into $4^2-4(2)(c-1) = 0$ which I kinda figure out that it's a rearranged version of $x^2=4fy \to x^2-4fy=0$ but I can't figure out why $x=4$ or why $f=2$ ?

Thanks!

Edit: look like the main problem is that I thought $4^2-4(2)(c-1)=0$ is a rearranged form of $x^2=4fy$ but it's actually a Quadratic's Discriminant $D=b^2-4ac$ which will answer me perfectly where 4 and 2 come from.

Comment: Yeah, but I really want to know why $x=4$ in that solution more than the c itself :)

Comment: Hmm, probably the teacher fault for not checking the question.

Comment: Did you write **exactly** what the question asks? As it is given all we can say is that $\;c\le 3\;$ ...assuming we're working on the reals, of course.

Comment: I can't write exactly what the question ask because it's in another language but I am certain that there is only "=" symbol in the solution sheet.

Comment: But you must ce certain that you translate as exactly as possible the question! You could also try to put the original question here. Maybe someone knows that other language...

Comment: Checking...I don't think I miss anything the only thing I didn't translate is the choices 1) 4.    2) -3, 2.    3) 3.     4) 0, 1

Comment: And then none is correct since, as already commented and answered below, the correct option is $\;c\le 3\;$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$c=-2x^2-4x+1=-2(x+1)^2+3\leq3.$$
You can use also your idea:
$$2^2-2(c-1)\geq0,$$ which gives $c\leq3$ again.

Comment: Do you have any pointer for me why the second solution work? how do you derive to 2 at that exact spot?

Comment: I used the following formula. $\frac{\Delta}{4}=\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2-ac.$ We say about polynomial $ax^2+bx+c,$ where $a\neq0.$